# Angular Async Pipe - Array in Object in Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, async-pipe

I am trying to Learn Async Pipe and how to use them.
however I have an issue with using Async Pipe in the following case;

I am using this fake/dummy API [Cat API](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
I can't figure how to retrieve the Object Data inside the observable value.

TS Code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from '../services/http/http.service';
import { facts } from '../interfaces/facts';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{
  facts$! : Observable<facts[]>
  constructor(private client : HttpService){

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.facts$ = this.client.getListFacts(25, 5)
  }

}
```

Interface

```
export interface facts {
  fact : string,
  length : number
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='home'>
  <ul style="margin: 0 0 0 0">
    <li *ngFor="let fact of (facts$ | async)">{{fact.fact}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

HTTP Service

```
  getListFacts(length : number, limit : number) : Observable<facts[]>{
    return this.client.get<facts[]>(`https://catfact.ninja/facts?max_length=${length}&limit=${limit}`)
```

I have tried to async pipe results, fact of facts list inside the HTML code, however it renders nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your typing of the API response is wrong. What comes from the API is an object with several properties related to pagination, and `data` array, which is what you're after. One way to consume it would be

```
getListFacts(length: number, limit: number) : Observable<facts[]> {
    return this.client
        .get<{ data: facts[] }>(`https://catfact.ninja/factsmax_length=${length}&limit=${limit}`)
        .pipe(map(({ data }) => data));
}
```

(Also, the interface should be named `Fact`, not `facts`: singular, because it represents a single entry, and uppercase, because that's the convention for types/interfaces/classes).

Comment: @MamdouhMorad Please accept the answer when it solved your problem

Comment: Hey, Sorry for asking again, but I am confused; 
I am now trying different API 

https://dog.ceo/dog-api/

Which I have defined an Interface for
` ` `
export interface Random{
  message : string,
  status : string
}
` ` `
and my http request is like this 

` ` `
  getRandomImage(): Observable<Random> {
    return this.client.get<Random>(`https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random`)
  }
` ` `
HTML 

` ` `
<div>
  <p *ngIf=" random$ | async">{{ random$.status }}</p>
</div>
` ` `

Comment: For what I understand, API returns an Object with message and status keys with value types string. 

Why is this observable I defined failing to render ? 

also Sorry, I am new here. I don't know how to accept as an answer

Comment: property 'status' does not exist on type 'Observable<Random>'